# Simple XML @Element (required = false) does not set the field to null if it has a not null default value

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am using simple xml and it is great. However, i have run into the following issue.

I have a Class with a String field that can be null but it has a default value of "XXXXXX":

```
@Element (required=false)
protected String tmRecordingFolder = TM_RECORDING_FOLDER_DEFAULT;
```

Everything works fine but if the tmRecordingFolder is set to null (Which is an allowed value) then the serialization works fine but when I deserialize the object the field tmRecordingFolder should be null but it has the default value TM_RECORDING_FOLDER_DEFAULT.

I would not like to initialize the field to null, as that is not the normal value. Why is not Simple XML setting the tmRecordingFolder to null?

Regards,
Javi

Comment: You can implement a `Converter`  for doing this.

Comment: Btw. maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386175/simpleframework-can-nulls-be-retained-in-collections/26434545#26434545